# Linq Include just one object from a one to many relation

Tags: linq

I have two tables with a one to many relation.

One Order has many Products.

I want to take a list of Orders with the free Product in each (one per order).

I've tried something like this:

```
this.ObjectContext.ORDERS.Include("PRODUCTS").Where(e=>e.PRODUCTS.price == 0).OrderBy(e => e.Order);
```

But this is not working.

Is there any other approach??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `PRODUCTS` is a collection, you can use the `Any()` extension method to find out if any product is free (alternatively, the `All()` method to find out if all products are free):

```
this.ObjectContext.ORDERS
                  .Include("PRODUCTS")
                  .Where(o => o.PRODUCTS.Any(p => p.price == 0))
                  .OrderBy(e => e.Order);
```

Based on your clarification of the desired output (all orders with optional free product), you can use this query:

```
this.ObjectContext.ORDERS
                  .Include("PRODUCTS")
                  .Select(o => new {
                      Order = o, 
                      FreeProduct = o.PRODUCTS.FirstOrDefault(p => p.price == 0)
                  });
```

It will return a sequence of an anomymous type containing the order, and the free product (or null if no free product exists).

Comment: What happens if there isn't any free product? Would it return the order without the PRODUCT??

Comment: @zapico No, it would not return the order at all. The orders without free products are just skipped. And if no order contains a free product, you will get an empty sequence.

Comment: :( Is there anyway to make it return the Order?? Or should I return them in other query and return both lists together?? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @zapico I thought you want only the orders with at least one free product?

Comment: No no, I want all the orders with a free product if it has it (there is no way to have more than one free product in an order)

Comment: @zapico Sounds the same to me. The products are returned together with the orders anyway. What should the desired output look like?

Comment: It would be something like: "Order 1 - Product Free 1, Order 2 - Product Free 2, Order 3 - Product Free 3, Order 4 - null, Order 5 - Product Free 4"... I want ALL the orders and, if they have a free product, the free product.

Comment: @zapico Ah, i see. I updated my answer with a query that should work.